# How can I Join this Tables Together

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have four tables, the EdiTransaction,EdiTransactionDetail,EdiDocType and Edi997Details in which the EdiTransaction table has a relationship with EdiDocType and EdiTransactionDetail but the Edi997Details has a relationship only with EdiTransaction and the rest they don't have (please click see image below)and I'm making a page wherein all the EdiTransaction with a corresponding DocType 856/810,EdiTransactionDetail with PO Number and it's Edi997Details. And now I'm very stuck on how to retrieve/JOIN the Edi997Details with the EdiTransaction table since the Edi997Details doesn't have a relationship with EdiDocType and EdiTransactionDetails.I was able able to retrieve them all except for the Edi997Details.

[image]

Here is the code in retrieving the EdiTransaction in EdiTransactionRepository:

```
public function getAsnDetails ($poNumber,$fileName, $page = 1 , $limit = 15) {

                $em = $this->getEntityManager();
                $query = $em->createQuery(

                        'SELECT partial a.{ediTransactionDetailId, poNumber},
                        partial b.{ediTransactionId, senderId, receiverId, gsNumber, isaNumber, fileName, transactionDate},
                        partial c.{ediDocTypeId, docType}
                        FROM MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTransactionDetail a
                        JOIN a.ediTransaction b
                        JOIN b.ediDocType c
                        WHERE b.fileName LIKE :fileName
                        AND a.poNumber LIKE :poNumber
                        AND c.docType = :doc_type
                        AND a.flag = 1 AND b.flag = 1 
                        ORDER BY b.transactionDate desc')

                ->setParameter('poNumber', "%$poNumber%")
                ->setParameter('fileName', "%$fileName%")
                ->setParameter('doc_type', 856)
                ->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $limit)
                ->setMaxResults($limit);

                $paginator = new Paginator ($query , $fetchJoinCollection = false );
                $paginator->setUseOutputWalkers(false);
                return $paginator;

        }
```

This is for the Edi997Details:

```
public function getAsnStatus(){

         $em = $this->getEntityManager();
         $query = $em->createQuery(
                 'SELECT  partial a.{id, ak301, ak401},
                 partial b.{errorCode, condition},
                 partial c.{edi997DetailId, errorCodeId, noOfTrans, acceptedTrans},
                 partial d.{ediTransactionId, senderId, receiverId, gsNumber, isaNumber, fileName}
                 FROM MatrixEdiBundle:Edi997SegmentInError a
                 JOIN a.ediAk403ErrorCodes b
                 JOIN a.edi997Details c
                 JOIN c.ediTransaction d
                 WHERE c.errorCodeId != 0
                 AND d.flag = 1');

                 return $query->getResult();


        }
```

Is there any way to JOIN the Edi997Details and EdiTransaction table where the DocType and EdiTransactionDetail will not be affected ? I need some help and ideas on how to solve this. I'm a beginner and my first time to visit this site.

Comment: Please get your code more simple (i.e with car or poneys). There is too much business naming in your example, it's hard to understand it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 table1 -> table2,table3
 table3 -> table1,table2
 table4 -> table2

select a.column,b.column,c.column,d from table1 a join table2 b join  
table3 join table4 d on d.column=b.column where...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit confused with this:-(

Answer (score 0):

The naming has no meaning for me, i'll try anyway with the relationship which is confusing you:

Edi997 <- ediTransaction -> ediDocType

Since doctrine is object oriented, you can do Edi997 ->GetEdiTransactions right? it is the same in the query

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder("Edi997"); //or other entity, it is for test purpose
$qb
  // [...]
  ->innerJoin("Edi997.ediTransactions","ediTransaction")
  ->innerJoin("ediTransaction.ediDocType","ediDocType")
 // [...]
 ->andWhere("ediDocType.attribute = :aParameter")
;
```